# Por que o AngularJS utiliza como padrão a # na URL?

Tags: angularjs

Me surgiu uma dúvida e gostaria de saber por que o Angular utiliza **#** na url?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para poder ter o funcionamento de Single Page Application, pois para usar rotas normais direto na `/` seria necessário configuração de server para não haver `refresh` na página, que nem sempre é tão simples. Então por default ele usa o `#`. Mas se você quiser você pode configurar para usar a `/` através do provider `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` no `.config()` do seu app e setando a tag `<base href="/" />`

De uma olhada na documentação: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 2):

*Hashbang, Hash, Tralha, Sustenido, HashTag* ou simplesmente `#` é quem determina qual página esta sendo chamada, isso quer dizer que `/#home` e `/index.html#home`são a mesma coisa, já que o index é o arquivo principal da aplicação.

Em outras palavras é a rota do arquivo.

```
/#home
/#sobre
/#contato
```

Essas rotas estão definidas no seu código. Por exemplo:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
  controller  : 'HomeController'
})
.when('/sobre', {
  templateUrl : 'pages/sobre.html',
  controller  : 'SobreController'
})
.when('/contato', {
  templateUrl : 'pages/contato.html',
  controller  : 'ContatoController'
})
```

Comment: Quem negativou poderia me dizer o porquê.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativei, mas sua resposta não responde a pergunta, simples.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente porque esta hiperligação é para a própria página (vide [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), não fazendo o navegador sair da página atual e carregar uma nova.

Este "endereço", que continua a ser mostrado no navegador, é substítuido por outras ações através de JavaScript.