# AngularJS ui-router application tem /#!/ na URL

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Eu tenho uma aplicação com **ui.router** funcionando normalmente, mas uma segunda aplicação tem um **"!"** depois do **"#"**

Ex: `http://localhost:8090/dev/#!/home`

Porque isso acontece?

O normal deveria ser: `http://localhost:8090/dev/#/home`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que o AngularJS utiliza como padrão a # na URL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172784/por-que-o-angularjs-utiliza-como-padr%c3%a3o-a-na-url)

Comment: Não é duplicado, a questão é o "#!" e não o "#"

Comment: Por isso está escrito "Possível".

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Resolvido: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365887/angularjs-ui-router-application-has-in-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é que o Angular está configurado para utilizar o padrão HTML5 para URLs sem *hash*, porém o browser não possui suporte ao modo. Da [documentação do Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#fallback-for-legacy-browsers):

> **Fallback for legacy browsers**
>   For browsers that support the HTML5 history API, $location uses the HTML5 history API to write path and search. If the history API is not supported by a browser, $location supplies a Hashbang URL. This frees you from having to worry about whether the browser viewing your app supports the history API or not; the $location service makes this transparent to you.

Traduzido livremente:

> **Fallback para navegadores antigos**
>   Para navegadores que suportam a API de histórico do HTML5, `$location` a utiliza para escrever pesquisas e caminhos. Se a API não for suportada pelo navegador, `$location` fornece uma URL hashbang [n.t.: `#!`]. Com isso o desenvolvedor não tem que se preocupar se o navegador suporta a API ou não; o serviço torna este processo transparente para você.