# Duvida sobre rotas Angular JS x ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net, rotas

Gostaria de sanar algumas dúvidas sobre Angular JS x ASP.NET MVC.

Criei uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC Vazia que irá trabalhar com WEB API, configurei todas minhas rotas com o AngularJS, criei uma página html e seus controllers, tudo com angularJS, minha dúvida é o seguinte, esses roteamento entre páginas é mandado alguma requisição para o servidor ? caso a página tenha algo para ser carregado como uma lista de registro via método $http.get a requisição é feita via ajax, ou seja a página não é carregada?

Fiquei nessa dúvida, pois no ASP.NET MVC todas chamadas de controllers é chamado uma requisição no servidor, pois o razor tem que construir as views e depois apresentar para o usuário certo?

Alguém entendido do assunto poderia descrever mais sobre quais as vantagens de usar o roteamento pelo angularJS e pelo ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa, uma breve explicação sobre as duas tecnologias:

#### Sobre o AngularJS

Ele é um *framework* para escrever aplicações *client-side*. Onde você desenvolve em JavaScript e tudo que for desenvolvido ali irá rodar do lado do cliente (no *browser*).

Na maior parte do tempo, só é feito o envio/recebimento **de dados** e, por isso, se usa alguma outra tecnologia *server-side* (como uma aplicação C# com ASP.NET, uma aplicação Ruby, ou qualquer outra).

Exemplificando, as requisições são feitas para o servidor e o mesmo responde com dados apenas (seja em JSON, XML, texto puro ou qualquer outro tipo disponível). Estes dados devem ser tratados do lado cliente.

É claro que nada te impede de fazer com que o servidor retorne um HTML ou algo similar, tenha em mente que o que eu digo é como normalmente se trabalha, não existem regras que realmente restrinjam isto.

#### Sobre o ASP.NET MVC

É um *framework web* para se trabalhar do lado servidor, receber, tratar e responder requisições.

Na maior parte das vezes as requisições são feitas para o servidor e o mesmo responde com uma página já montada, isto é, todo o tratamento dos dados são feitos do lado do servidor e enviados para o cliente.

Claro que pode existir tratamento de dados do lado do cliente, usando JavaScript, mas aí é outra história.

Agora, vamos às suas perguntas:

> Esses roteamento entre páginas é mandado alguma requisição para o servidor?

Não. A ideia é justamente que não se faça (quase) nenhum contato com o servidor ao trocar a troca (o estado) da aplicação.

> Caso a página tenha algo para ser carregado como uma lista de registro via método `$http.get` a requisição é feita via `Ajax`, ou seja a página não é carregada?

Exatamente. Este é o propósito das requisições assíncronas.

> Fiquei nessa dúvida, pois no ASP.NET MVC todas chamadas de *controllers* é chamado uma requisição no servidor, pois o *razor* tem que construir as views e depois apresentar para o usuário certo?

Obviamente. O ASP.NET é um *framework web* para o **servidor**.

Basicamente, pense no seguinte fluxo.

- O browser solicita uma página
- O servidor recebe a solicitação e envia para a aplicação ASP.NET MVC
- A aplicação faz o tratamento da requisição, delega a execução para um *controller* que, por sua vez, entrega a execução nas mãos do *Razor* que vai executar todo o código da *view* e entregar um HTML bonitinho pro *browser* interpretar
- O *browser* recebe a resposta e mostra o HTML para o usuário
- Isso se repete quantas vezes for necessário

> Alguém entendido do assunto poderia descrever mais sobre quais as vantagens de usar o roteamento pelo angularJS e pelo ASP.NET MVC?

Não sou entendido do assunto, mas posso te dizer que não existe vantagem de se usar sobre o outro. Cada um deles serve a um propósito específico e eles são completamente diferentes.

Se a aplicação é uma SPA que só precisa consultar dados no servidor (pelo menos na maior parte do tempo), provavelmente vai ser preciso usar o sistema de rotas do AngularJS. Se é uma aplicação normal, onde a maioria das requisições para o servidor retornarão uma página completa, bem provável é preferível usar o roteamento padrão.

---

Leitura Indicada:

- [O que é SPA e no que se diferencia de uma página não SPA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212952/18246)
- [Por que o AngularJS utiliza como padrão a # na URL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172784/18246)
- [Por que usar o AngularJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123913/18246)
- [Quais as principais diferenças entre jQuery e AngularJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21482/18246)